# connect to database retrieved at runtime using spring + hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am using spring + hibernate transaction manager in the my project. Initially I am connecting to main database and retrieving several projects in a company, say if there are 200 projects each project will have database associated with it, I want to connect to database associated with the project that is selected by user at run time.

Is there any ideal way to connect to database at run time?

Comment: Please see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756346/how-to-set-database-name-at-runtime-in-spring-hibernate

Comment: We used a multi tenancy solutions which I blogged about [here](https://mdeinum.wordpress.com/2007/01/05/one-application-per-client-database/). Which would be suitable for you also (without even having to know at runtime which projects there are). Basically you could create your own implementation of the `TargetRegistry` which based on the selection creates (or reuses) a `DataSource`. The remainder of your application could  be simply using the single datasource.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Spring abstraction [AbstractRoutingDataSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html) that has been around for a long time, and that fits your bill

> The general idea is that a routing DataSource acts as an intermediary
>   - while the ‘real’ DataSource can be determined dynamically at runtime based upon a lookup key.

There is a good [post](https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/) and a newer [tutorial](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/12/28/spring-3-2-5-abstractroutingdatasource-example/), where you can learn more details.

Comment: Thanks !! I went through post , but the datasource is predefined in spring config file. As I don't know the database names initially and i can get that run time, I cannot predefine datasource in spring config file. Is there way to set datasource dynamically on fly?