# Is there a way to map mutliple databases with same table names in a dynamic way?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

First time I encounter this problem. The situation is:

I have more than 100 SQL databases, each one correspond to a different company and each one have the same three tables (same table names, same column names, same column data type).

Is there some way to map all these databases dynamically?

With dynamically I mean to have one class to which I can refer and make any *CRUD operation.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set database name at runtime in Spring Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756346/how-to-set-database-name-at-runtime-in-spring-hibernate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I could see what I wanted to do:

Basically I needed to change my data source in run time, for that I used a spring framework interface called `AbstracRoutingDataSource`.

Example:

Implementing AbstractRoutingDataSource:

```
public class MultiRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {
    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return DBContextHolder.getCurrentDb();
    }
}
```

DatabaseContextHolder:

```
public class DBContextHolder {

    private static final ThreadLocal<DBTypeEnum> contextHolder = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void setCurrentDb(DBTypeEnum dbType) {
        contextHolder.set(dbType);
    }
    public static DBTypeEnum getCurrentDb() {
        return contextHolder.get();
    }
    public static void clear() {
        contextHolder.remove();
    }
}
```

Database type enum:

```
public enum DBTypeEnum{

  DATASOURCE1("DATASOURCE1"),
  DATASOURCE2("DATASOURCE2");

DBTypeEnum(final String dbTypeEnum){
        this.dbTypeEnum = dbTypeEnum;
    }

    private String dbTypeEnum;

    public String dbTypeEnum(){
        return dbTypeEnum;
    }

}
```

Persistence configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "base.packages.path",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "multiEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "multiTransactionManager"
)
public class PersistenceConfiguration {
    private final String PACKAGE_SCAN = "base.package.path";

    @Bean(name = "dataSource1")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource1")
    public DataSource dataSource1() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource2")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource2")
    public DataSource dataSource2() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "multiRoutingDataSource")
    public DataSource multiRoutingDataSource() {
        Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<>();
        targetDataSources.put(DBTypeEnum.DATASOURCE1, dataSource1());
        targetDataSources.put(DBTypeEnum.DATASOURCE2, dataSource2());

        MultiRoutingDataSource multiRoutingDataSource = new MultiRoutingDataSource();
        multiRoutingDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(dataSource1());
        multiRoutingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);
        return multiRoutingDataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "multiEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean multiEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(multiRoutingDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(PACKAGE_SCAN);
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return em;
    }
    @Bean(name = "multiTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager multiTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
                = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
                multiEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean(name = "dbSessionFactory")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean dbSessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(multiRoutingDataSource());
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(PACKAGE_SCAN);
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);
        return properties;
    }


}
```

Then you need to have all of your database information in a .properties file:

```
spring.datasource1.jdbcUrl=jdbc:sql:sql-url:3306/datasource1
spring.datasource1.username=username
spring.datasource1.password=password
spring.datasource1.driver-class-name= Driver

spring.datasource2.jdbcUrl=jdbc:sql:sql-url:3306/datasource2
spring.datasource2.username=username
spring.datasource2.password=password
spring.datasource2.driver-class-name= Driver
```

Then you need to map your entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_name")
@Getter
@Setter
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", columnDefinition = "varchar(17)")
    private String id;

    //more fields...
}
```

I used spring CrudRepositories interface for this entity

```
public interface IMyEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, String> {

}
```

Finally my controller is prepared to change datasource depending on a JSON field in my request.

JSON:

```
{
  "dataSource":"DATASOURCE1"
  //more fields ...
}
```

RESTController:

```
@PutMapping("/url/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> editMyEntity(@RequestBody RequestObject request @PathVariable String id){

    DBContextHolder.setCurrentDb(DBTypeEnum.valueOf(request.getDataSource);
    iMyEntitiRepository.getMyEntity(id);


    //... 

}
```